# View latlng in popup after moving marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geolocation, latitude-longitude, marker

I want to show on popup the lat and lng also after i move the marker if the initial position is not correct.
Is it possible to view in popup the new coordinate after that the marker has been moved?

```
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').fitWorld();

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1
    }).addTo(map);

    function onLocationFound(e) {
        var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
        var myMarker = L.marker((e.latlng), {draggable: true}).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " " + e.latlng +" meters from this point").openPopup();
        myMarker.on("dragend", function(e){
        var newCoords = e.target.getLatLng().toString();
       });

        L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
    }

    function onLocationError(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);
    map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call `.binPopup(text)` again:

```
var myMarker = L.marker((e.latlng), {draggable: true}).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " " + e.latlng +" meters from this point").openPopup();

myMarker.on("dragend", function(e){
        var newCoords = e.target.getLatLng().toString();
        myMarker.bindPopup("New Coords: "+newCoords).openPopup();
});
```

To split latlng into seperate parts, you can use the `.latlng.lat` / `.latlng.lng` properties

```
myMarker.on("dragend", function(e){
        var latlng = e.target.getLatLng();
        myMarker.bindPopup("New Coords: Lat: "+latlng .lat +" Lng: "+latlng .lng).openPopup();
});
```

Comment: thank you so much! and if i want to split in Lat: xx and Long: yy?

Comment: @CartoLover I updated the answer. Please accept this answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

you can split with substring(startposition,endposition);

```
 var lat = newCoords.substring(7, 16);
 var lng = newCoords.substring(17, 27);
 myMarker.bindPopup("New Coords: "+lat +lng).openPopup();
```